# Nav li items moving slighlty when hovering on a drop down item

Tags: html, css, navbar

Below is the html code for a simple navbar i have made. My issue is that when i hover over the products link to show the drop down items all other navbar items move left slighlty. I realise i may be going about this the wrong way as i am still learning.

```css
.main-nav {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.main-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.products li {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.products-list a {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.products a {
  display: none;
}

.products {
  position: absolute;
}

.products-list:hover .products a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li class="products-list"><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
        <ul class="products">
          <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!--   wrapper ends   -->
</div>
```

Note: i have given certain elements a border to help me in positioning them.

Comment: I tried it in both Firefox and Chrome (after properly closing your open elements), I don't see the other navbar items moving left on hover. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELPwpK

Comment: It's because the dropdown adds a scrollbar (on small screens) to the right of the screen so everything shifts left 20px.  Unless that's not the shift you are talking about?

Comment: just to add my codepen link with updated code: https://codepen.io/CrispyChris/pen/WJbXGp i also cant work out why i have a gap between 'products' and 'services' as highlighted by the little orange border? cant figure out what it is.

Comment: Your codepen still does not shift anything to the left on hover in firefox or chrome, so I don't understand your question. I also have no idea what gap you're talking about between products and services. It looks pretty consistent with the spacing between that and the other menu items.

Comment: Got it, it was because when i hovered over products the dropdown list didn't fit on the screen as i had it so the scrollbar pushed everything over. Thanks for your help, i will try to explain more clearly in future!

Answer (score 0):

U had added extra `li` before **service**

```css
.main-nav {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.main-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.products li {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.products-list a {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.products a {
  display: none;
}

.products {
  position: absolute;
}

.products-list:hover .products a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li class="products-list"><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
        <ul class="products">
          <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div>
```